# PostgreSQL 10 logical replication trigger function not executed

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, multi-master-replication

I've implemented the Logical replication in PostgreSQL 10 within 2 db in 2 different server and I'm aware that the sequences are not sync so I created a trigger function like this in both database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_ogc_fid()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
Declare 
iInt integer;
BEGIN
execute 'Select nextval('|| chr(39) || 'address_ogc_fid_seq' || chr(39) ||');' into iInt;
NEW.ogc_fid = iInt;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_ogc_fid_address
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON address
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_ogc_fid();
```

A part from the fact that is actually using just odd `ID` in the DB1 and even in DB2 why is the function not triggered in the second database?

If I insert a record in the DB1 i have `ID` 3, it do the replication and in the DB2 i have the same record with the same `ID`, I'm going to check the sequence in the DB2 and is still 1 instead of be 3.

Now I'm going to insert a record in the DB2 and I have `ID` 2 and then 4.

For what I want to achieve that is a master master system, in case that one is down I can write in the second one I don't really care too much but thinking in case of a disaster when I'm going to restore the DB in the server that is down (maybe with a pg-dump backup) I need to update all the sequences to start writing from where was before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Triggers are by default not executed on logical standby servers, because the parameter `session_replication_role` is set to `replica` when the changes are applied.

You can change a trigger so that it fires even during replication:

```
ALTER TABLE mytab
   ENABLE ALWAYS TRIGGER atrigger;
```

Comment: This will make the trigger fire, but if the goal is to keep sequences in sync across a multi-master setup, I don't think this trigger is going to do it...

Comment: I've used this tutorial, I'm using `wal_level = logical` https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-logical-replication-with-postgresql-10-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @NickBarnes I agree. I just tried to explain why the triggers don't fire.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE  TRIGGER yours_trigger_name
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON yours_table_name
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE yours_trigger_procedure_name();

alter table yours_table_name enable always trigger yours_trigger_name;
alter table yours_table_name enable replica trigger yours_trigger_name;
```

This construction works in replication, but if you want to use `UPDATE OF yours_field_name` instead of just `UPDATE` it doesn't work. I don't know why)))